# NServiceBus Studio - Starting with an Event

Tags: nservicebus

I'm following along with the NSB video on TekPub (http://tekpub.com/view/nsb/1) as an introduction to the NSB
Studio (great work btw). I can create the PetShop example just fine, but now I'm
looking to create my own system. In the PetShop example, the process starts off
with the Sales component (in the FrontEnd endpoint) *sending* a SubmitOrder
command on the bus. When the SubmitOrder command was created, Studio created a
SubmitOrderSender, which is what is hosted in the FrontEnd endpoint.

In my existing system, I have a process that will do some work, and I want to
start the NSB process with an *event*, not a *command*. In Studio, I created a
new Service ("Foo") and manually added a new Component ("XxxRecievedSender"). I
then had the XxxReceivedSender publish an event ("XxxReceived"). Then I right
clicked on the XxxReceived event, and added a new subscriber ("Notifications").
Studio created the Notifications service and added a "XxxReceivedProcessor"
which subscribes to the XxxReceivedEvent.

The differences I noticed from the video are that the SubmitOrderSender that is
generated has an ISubmitOrder interface, and a Send(SubmitOrder) method. Since I
manually created my XxxReceivedSender, I didn't have those, so I added them
(except Publish instead of Send). Then, in my mvc frontend, I added the
IXxxReceivedSender to the home controller, and then executed Sender.Push(new
XxxReceived()). I then got errors that I needed to add MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
to the .configure() and then more errors that the queues weren't created. Once
I fixed those two things, the app runs, but when the event is published, the
XxxReceivedProcessor isn't received it.

I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what it
is. Any advice? As Studio is a brand new feature, I'd be very interested
in the proper way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the UnicastBusConfig in your subscribing endpoint to see that there is an entry in there telling NServiceBus to subscribe to your event at the MVC endpoint.

If that's handled, then start the subscriber by itself and see that a message arrives at your publisher. If so, then start the publisher and see that the message is processed and that there are no messages in your error queue.

Comment: There is. In the subscriber endpoint there is this

<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
<MessageEndpointMappings>

<add Messages="MyProject.Contract.XXXReceived, MyProject.Contract" Endpoint="MyProject.FrontEnd" />

</MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>